# how to replace OnLinkClick with setInterval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multi-level

I have copied some code that I am trying to modify. There is a link in my html like so:

```
<div id="dl-menu">
   <ul class="dl-menu dl-menuwrapper">
      <li><a href="#"><div id="clickable" ></div></a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

and in my javascript:

```
$( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu( {
    onLinkClick :  function( ev ) {
    nextPage( ( 'animation' ) );
    }
});
```

The function nextPage creates an animation:

```
function nextPage(options) {

        if( isAnimating ) {
            return false;
        }

        isAnimating = true;

        var $currPage = $pages.eq( current );

        if(options.showPage){
            if( options.showPage < pagesCount - 1 ) {
                current = options.showPage;
            }
etc...
```

I won't copy the whole thing unless required as it works. What I am trying to do is to disassociate the funtion nextPage from the dlmenu so to speak. I just want the function nextPage to fire up using setInterval or some button.

I am learning jquery so I am copying code that I don't fully understand. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your selector is wrong, you're selecting by id, but the element has a class.

Comment: It's a copy paste mistake, the div has an id of dl-menu and the ul has a class of dl-menu

Comment: So, you want the function to fire a set delay after page load?  Just use `setTimeout(function() {//function here}, //delay in ms);`